# Why are my apps not using the full internet speed?

Tags: 16.04, networking

My computer has a great Wifi card on it, and I have a great router. I get 60 megabits (around 7.5 megabytes) per second, and when I go to speedtest sites, they always say I have 60 mbps going to my computer with ubuntu 16.04 on it. The problem is, when I download something using apt-get, Chromium, git, or any other application on my machine, it only gives me 1 megabyte per second, if I'm lucky. It usually says the rate is 500 kilobytes a second, and that's absolutely ridiculous since I'm supposed to be getting at least 7!

Does Ubuntu support that speed? Why were the speedtests working yet downloading things at that speed fails?

As a sidenote, I know it's not my router or wifi card. Might it be the driver?

Comment: because they are serving more than just you. thus you have to time share with everyone accessing that server, and all the server connections in between you and where you are getting the file. if you can get a download rate of 2 MB you are doing well.

Comment: There are a lot of questions in your post. Firstly, I'd suggest switching mirrors for apt, to a server closer to you. See if that solves part of the problem. Second, it may be chromium, but try an alternative browser like Firefox to be certain it's not the connection. Finally, speedtest.net is notoriously unreliable as a true test of speed. Realistically, speedtest.org is more reliable.

Comment: Side note, your download speed is dependent on many factors, any one of them could be limiting your speed. I doubt it is the OS, or the WiFi drivers. If it were, you would be having a lot more trouble with your connection. As to your question about Ubuntu supporting those speeds, Ubuntu is limited only by the connection, there is no internal speed cap.

Comment: @ThatGuy -- yes getting a mirror as close as possible will help, but unless he a a T1 line or fiberoptics  500KB - 1.5MB is normal ... 2MB is cooking.  speedtest sites connect you to the closest node and dedicate to you exclusively for a few minutes.... that's how they maximize throughput. I doubt there is anything wrong with his software or hardware

Comment: @ravery I tend to agree, but he stated it was also affecting git and downloads within Chromium. My point is more to provide him with basic tools to troubleshoot. If one thing doesn't work, then process of elimination, until he can narrow down the source of the issue.

Comment: @ravery If 1.5 is normal, then why am I only getting .5? I've change the mirrors as well, to no avail.

Comment: I said 500kb-1.5MB is normal  thus you are in normal range.  to get 1.5MB you have to have few intermediary connections and a relatively unbusy file server at the source